# If a = 3 + b, which of the following is true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

See: [Nova GRE Math Bible. Page-$234$.](https://greworldknowlegde.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/nova-gre-math-bible.pdf)

> Problem #06
>
> If a = 3 + b, which of the following is true?
>
> (I) a > b + 2.5
>   (II) a < b + 2.5
>   (III) a > 2 + b
>
> (A) I only
>   (B) II only
>   (C) III only
>   (D) I and II only
>   (E) I and III only

The given answer is (A), (C), and (D).

How come?

My calculation was (E).

Comment: Am I looking at the wrong one because the book says for that problem "Hence, the answer is (E): I and III are true."

Comment: `The given answer is (A), (C), and (D)` There can be no multiple choices in the case of overlapping answers ending in "*only*". **I** and **III** are true, therefore **(E)**.

Comment: @Brenton, hmmm...... LOL..... my printed book has a printing mistake. LOL. I just discovered it.

Comment: If $a=4,b=1$ then $II$ is not satisfied!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippit from the link you included.

[image]

Comment: my printed book has a printing mistake.I just discovered it.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right. A good way to find out is giving values. I always do that. In India we call it the jugaad method. Let $b=0$ and $a=b+3=3$. Now you can just test the values.